# Why are only some options grayed out when all are unavailable after raising a flag?

Tags: bug, flags, flag-dialog

I have a pending flag on a question for being too broad. After the author clarified in the comments, it seemed they were trying to make a malicious program. I clicked flag again and noticed that while two options are grayed out (the flag I used and duplicate question), none of the options could be clicked.

[image: The "You already have a pending flag" window with 2 of 5 options disabled.]

Why are two of the five options visually disabled when none of them can be clicked? Shouldn't all 5 be grayed out?

Comment: Technically, "duplicate" is a subset of "should be closed".

Comment: Sure, my question is more that none of the options are clickable, yet only two are visibly grayed out. Your comment helps explains why those are the two grayed out, but not why the other 3 are not grayed out despite not being clickable.

Comment: Pay attention to the dialog title and the button text.  This is not to add more flags.

Comment: Well, you can *still* flag it with non-disabled reasons *after* you retract the current pending flag... (and mod flag is *always* available)

Comment: @Andrew T.: That's so confusing. So exactly how many times does a user need to go through this dialog to retract their flag and apply a new one?

Comment: @BoltClock 2 times: 1 for retracting the current pending one, then 1 for applying with different reason.

Comment: @Hans Passant: If this is not to add more flags, why does the UI contain affordances to do just that? That's the premise of this question.

Comment: I was about to report the same bug. [I know for a fact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD9IW.png) that it has been possible to use multiple flags on the same post before, so it is either changed or this is a bug. The fact that those other options are not grayed makes me think it's the latter.

Comment: @AndrewT. "_and mod flag is always available_" [In this case it isn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG7eC.png).

Comment: @Ivar AFAIK, you can only have 1 active flag on a post. If your "off-topic" flag has been handled (i.e. the question is closed), then you can flag it again with another flag. But you can't have 2 active flags at the same time on a same post.

Comment: We used to not be able to retract flags, but I seem to recall having the ability to have both a closure flag and a mod-flag active on a given post at the same time before I had the ability to vote to close. This probably has to do with the change implementing the ability to retract flags.

Comment: You can't have two flags active simultaneously, @Tiny. Doesn't matter what type of flags, if you've raised a flag and it's still pending, you can't raise another on the same post... However, *once your close flag has been handled or retracted*, you should be able to raise a rude flag, or vice-versa.

Comment: @Shog9 Has this always been like this? In 2015 I've been able to flag a post for both POB and spam [within 12 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI60h.png). It is possible that the first one was marked helpful within that time, but I'm also pretty confident that I've been able to select other options as well for pending flags before.

Comment: It's been that way since 2013, @Ivar. But, close flags are different. As Tiny notes, you used to be able to have both 1 close flag and one "moderator" flag active on the same post. In fact, you still can - you just need to have the question open in two different browser windows and the flag dialog loaded in each before you raise the first flag; the backend doesn't restrict it, only the frontend cares. Heck, you could script it or use the API if you wished... That said, I wouldn't recommend it. Folks used to get the mods pretty irritated by raising multiple flags to "double-dip" on closure.